# build and execute a bash script from a java script with spaces

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix

i am creating a java application which is will be GUI for a bash script..

The application will be used browse the script location and enter 2 other parameters..

and build and execute the command..

so the execute part will be like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(scriptPath + parameter1 + parameter2);
```

if the command work if the script's location doesn't has spaces in it..

but when it has spaces it stops when it reach the first space..
and it gives me "java.io.IOException:" exeption..that the file is not found..

i have tried replacing the spaces with backspace and space..

```
scriptPath.replace(" ", "\\ ")
```

i also tried adding quotes before and after the path

```
"\"" + scriptPath + "\""
```

and i have tried them both together..

```
"\"" + scriptPath.replace(" ", "\\ ") + "\""
```

but none of them had worked..

any help will be appreciated..

regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Runtime`'s `exec(String)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) just splits the string on whitespace; it doesn't understand any sort of quoting. Instead, you can use its [`exec(String[])` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), which takes an array, so doesn't have to apply any splitting logic:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] { scriptPath, parameter1, parameter2 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ProcessBuilder instead. It has a constructor that lets you add the parameters as separate strings, and should handle spaces.